# Importing flat file and Creating reports sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs-2008

I have a ragged right flat file  which has 168 columns. 
I will get this type of flat file daily and need to create various reports and send these reports to various departments of my company. 
My task is to load this flat file into sql server database for reporting purposes. The 168 columns should go to 22 different tables and when storing this in different ttables, it should be in the correct datatypes 
Can anyone suggest a good process to do this.

I need to covert the column before loading to each table.

and from that table, i will create reports.

Thank you for your time help !

Comment: Is your flat file delimited? If not what are the rules for column splits. Is there sufficient information in the file to route the data to 22 different tables? Do any of the rows go to more than 1 table?

Comment: Anjana, the details you have given us is not enough to give any answer. On what basis are you splitting the columns, when you talk about reports are you just pulling all the data or is it the audit reports that you are looking for?

Comment: I have the the start and end position of each columns and using the ragged right option in the SSIS import/Export wizard to load the flat file into SQL server. For example, I have two fields, EmployeNumber and JoinDate,  100230003/12/2012 . The start position of EmployeeNumber is 1 and the start position of joinDate is 8.  Based on this start position I have to split 100230003/12/2012 into 1002300 and 03/12/2012 and these values should go to EmployeNumber and JoinDate columns respectively.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I worked for similar type of project and here is the scenario and what i did if it helps you.

***Scenario*** 
files were dumped via FTP at midnight, this file should be processed and generate report everyday [early first hour].

*Solution*
I fixed a  folder to dump file everyday and designed a SSIS to import into a large table [168 columns table on our case] i.e.Table ImportStaging, also I had column dateImported and filename to keep track for file and date imported.
and the I had a procedure to populated other tables. and SSRS report on place.

Now I designed a SQL job,

Step 1: Import using SSIS package

Step 2: SSIS package to move imported files into FileDumpYard drive

Step 3: Exec proc   --[populated into proper tables and generate summaries]

and scheduled this job for early morning.
that's it

My reports were ready before I get off my bed  :)